# Multi Floor navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, ekf-localization, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

What is the best way for localization in multi floor map with indigo? is there any support with this and how to deal with the maps?

Much appreciation for your help.

Wassim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246854/multi-floor-navigation/) by [wassimhariri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26309/wassimhariri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spiritninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/39726/spiritninja/) on 2019-07-24**:
@wassimhariri I guess it's pretty late of me askign, but were you able to find a working procedure for multi floor navigation (localization) in indigo or Kinetic? I've seen your other [query](https://answers.ros.org/question/245542/problem-with-mongodb-for-multi-map-navigation/). I had the same notion as the mongo_DB part is a pretty old stack now.

It would be helpful if you could share your approach in case you were able to get the multi floor navigation working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never used none of these personally though:

- U-Texas Austin is maintaining [multi_level_map](http://wiki.ros.org/multi_level_map) package. Seems to be still used for their research as of today.
- A bit outdated, there's also [multi-floor mapping with drones at U. Penn](http://www.ros.org/news/2010/09/autonomous-multi-floor-indoor-navigation-with-a-mav.html). Don't know if the code is opensourced.
- The famous PR2-get-me-sandwitch-at-Subway-downstairs demo code [seems to be opensourced](http://www.ros.org/news/2010/09/autonomous-multi-floor-indoor-navigation-with-a-mav.html).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2